# UndefinedError: 'flask_paginate.Pagination object' has no attribute 'skip'

Tags: python, flask, pagination

I am trying to paginate data coming from backend using flask_paginate. I followed, https://pythonhosted.org/Flask-paginate/ to get it implemented.

My view -

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang='en'>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>AT - Monitoring System</title>

</head>
<body>
{{ pagination.info }}
{{ pagination.links }}
<table id="myTable"> 
<thead> 
<tr> 
    <th>Sector ID</th> 
    <th>Username</th> 
    <th>Password</th> 
    <th>Camera Name</th>
    <th>Camera ID</th>  
    <th>Recording status</th> 
</tr> 
</thead> 
<tbody> 
{% for each in response %}
<tr>
    <td>{{ loop.index + pagination.skip }}</td>
    <td>{{each[0]}} </td> 
    <td>{{each[1]}} </td> 
    <td>{{each[2]}}</td> 
    <td>{{each[3]}}</td> 
    <td>&nbsp;{{each[4]}}</td> 
    <td>{{each[5]}}</td>
</tr>
{% endfor %}
</tbody> 
</table>
{{ pagination.links }} 
</body>
</html>
```

Python Code -

```
APP = flask.Flask(__name__)
@APP.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def index():
    """ Displays the index page accessible at '/'
    """
    search = False
    q = request.args.get('q')
    if q:
        search = True

    page = request.args.get('page', type = int, default = 1)
    pagination = Pagination(page=page, total=len(Backend()), search=search, record_name='response')
    if request.method == 'GET':
        return flask.render_template('index.html',
                                     response = data,
                                     pagination = pagination
                                     )
if __name__ == '__main__':
    data = Backend()
    Thread(target=main_loop).start()
    APP.debug=True
    APP.run(port=63000)
```

I tried to find documentation which shows me the usage of pagination.skip(), but can't find anything. On removing this function, I see the no. of pages on my browser, but on content is not displayed as per the page nos. There is definitely something, I am missing big time. The other examples online are very different to the example mentioned in https://pythonhosted.org/Flask-paginate/